# My sh codes don't work, help needed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, opensuse

I'm learning to work with linux but it isn't working out

Script 1, did work until I updated opensuse:

```
#!/bin/bash
useradd Test 
passwd Test123
mkhomedir_helper Test
```

(It now says that all these commands don't exist)

Script 2, I can only get into my MySql console and he doesn't execute everything:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root -ppassword
sleep 3
CREATE USER 'Test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

I would really appreciate some help here since I'm new to linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following cmd:

```
echo $PATH
```

Output should be list some paths as below

```
/Usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

If not then run below command:

```
export PATH="/Usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
```

Now try running above script-1, if it still gives same error, then you are missing some packages, install 'pam' package which contains mkhomedir_helper binaries, so run following command to install pam.

```
zypper in pam
```

Script 2, to run mysql query from command line or as a shell script you need to use '-e' option, change the script 2 as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root -ppassword -e 'CREATE USER "Test"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "password"'
```

Comment: Script 1 isn't something I can test atm since I'm using opensuse on a virtualbox on a computer which is very secure (So I'll have to test this later) but Script 2 works very good with no errors, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any Idea how I can add (to script 2) a small line to also create a database for the user I just made and give it the rights it needs?

Comment: Add the following line(mydb is db name):
 mysql -u root -ppassword -e 'GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO "Test"@"localhost"'

Comment: This doesn't work but for my understanding this only gives the rights to test and doesn't make the database right? because I don't have the code to make a database either

Comment: if you need to create database then run:
mysql -u root -ppassword -e 'create database mydb'

Comment: I did the zypper in pam and it said that I have the last available update so that can't be it, any other solutions?